# Cocoa - NSFileManager removeItemAtPath Not Working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, nsfilemanager

I am trying to delete a file, but somehow nsfilemanager will not allow me to do so. I do use the file in one line of code, but once that action has been ran, I want the file deleted. I have logged the error code and message and I get error code: 4 and the message:

```
"text.txt" could not be removed
```

Is there a way to fix this error "cleanly" (without any hacks) so that apple will accept this app onto their Mac App Store?

EDIT:

This is what I am using:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
```

Thanks,

kevin

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you post more code so we can see what's going on? Also, is this the same application you needed `BLAuthentication` for?

Comment: Wow, funny that we met in the same question again huh? No its different, and in this one I'm submitting it to the App Store in which case they don't allow the allowing of "root access". I have made changes to the question to include what I am using.

Comment: Try using `unlink([filePath fileSystemRepresentation]);`, that is the POSIX way to remove a file.

Comment: I should say that it decrements a file's link count (which may result in deletion). See the [`unlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html) page. I'm still not sure whether it will make any difference.

Comment: Kevin, OK, just making sure. I was going to point that out, just in case. Also, as a general recommendation, make your code look like this and tell us what it prints out: `NSError *error; [[NSFileManager defaultMAnager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error]; NSLog(@"%@", error);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Error code 4 seems to be [NSNoSuchFileError](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFileNoSuchFileError).  If the file you want to delete really exists, then you have got the path wrong. You'll need to post some code if you want us to tell you exactly how you got the path wrong.

If the file doesn't exist, you can ignore the error.

Comment: Hi I faced this problem, turns out my file name is wrong. So either filename is wrong or filepath is wrong, it will give Error Code 4. Cheers.

Comment: @Rocotilos: "File path" usually includes the actual name of the file.

Comment: How to you in general go about finding the actual error in the docs/source?

Comment: @fabian789 In this case I typed in the following Google search [nserror codes site:developer.apple.com](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rls=en&q=nserror+codes+site:developer.apple.com&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in swift.For some reason fileManager.removeItemAtPath did't work and I changed fileManager.removeItemAtPath(filePath) to fileManager.removeItemAtURL(fileURL) and it works fine.

```
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    let documentsFolderUrl = fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)

    let soundURL = documentsFolderUrl!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(recording.path)
    let stringTrimmedFilePath = "trimmed_\(recording.path)"
    let trimmedSoundURL = documentsFolderUrl!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(stringTrimmedFilePath)
    var error: NSError?
    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(trimmedSoundURL, error: &error)
```

Comment: Seems like a bug with fileManager.removeItemAtPath

Answer (score 2):

First you need to pick the path for the document directory then you can delete the file.
Only remove statement is not sufficient.

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *databaseFile = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:databaseFile error:NULL];
```

use this for solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your path is incorrect

Use the following

```
NSString *str = [outputFieldURL path];
```

instead of

```
NSString *str = [outputFieldURL absoluteString];
```

The method "removeItemAtPath:" need the local path of file, If you want to remove using url, you should use `-removeItemAtURL:`

Comment: For those looking for answers about Code: 4 errors when working with any of the "Path" family of functions this is the first thing to check. If you use NSURL absoluteString it will have "file:///" prepended and that will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out of something very important when you use NSFileManager. You have to be aware of App Sandboxing.

```
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
```

This line return the path document directory of your app sandboxed. When you create a file with FileManager in your document directory (for e.g) don't save the full file path but only the path from the current document directory.

You'll be able to recreate the full path of your created file.

Hope (after 5 years) help over developers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Default method AFNetworking 3.0 don't refresh that you downloader files.

If you want rewrite this file in Objective-C +iOS9.0, you need do that:

```
- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *) downloadDocsFromUrl:(NSString *) url withSuccesBlock:(DocModelBlock) docModelBlock withErrorBlock:(ErrorBlock) errorBlock {

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.sessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:&error];

        if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSURL *urlPath = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];

            if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:urlPath.path]) {
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:urlPath.path error:&error];
            }
        }

        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            errorBlock(error);
        } else {
            docModelBlock(filePath);
        }
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];

    return downloadTask;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Why do you think this solves a question that is seven years old? To me, it looks like much code and I would not know which parts I could need if I had the same problem as the OP